# crawl php open source forum?

Tags: php, open-source, web-crawler

is there an easy way to crawl open source php forums and put them in categories in my own forum, eg. "windows", "mac" and so on?

Comment: i've read a tutorial about general crawling technique but i wonder if one somehow could crawl their information but sort them under own categories "windows", "mac", "linux" so that the user specifically could chose what to read. did you give me -1?=)

Comment: I did not downvote you, but your question is lacking substance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ethical to go around scraping everyone else's content; Unless they have a public RSS feed I think you'll have to figure it out on your own.